# How quickly do the hunters respawn?

Tags: evolve

Sometimes I feel that killed hunters respawn in the middle of a fight. How long do the hunters stay dead?

Comment: "Incapped" is a downed hunter, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - The timer always starts at zero when the Hunters first land onto the    map at the start of a Hunt game.
> - If a Hunter is incapped (or if you    have 2 strikes and are killed)    it will add 10 seconds to the dropship    timer.
> - If a Monster stages up, 25 seconds are added to the dropship       timer.
> - The dropship doors will always open and spawn hunters once    the    countdown timer hits zero. Hunters must enter the dropship before
>     the timer hits zero in order to respawn.
> - The maximum timer on the    dropship is two minutes.

[Evolve: Stage 2 Release Notes 2.00](https://talk.turtlerockstudios.com/t/evolve-stage-2-release-notes-2-00-pc-only/87794/3)

Answer (score 0):

To add additional detail, the timer starts at zero as @user598527 stated. The catch is that not only does each hunter being sent to the dropship increase the timer by 10 seconds, but *each of these increases are permanent*. When the timer resets *it goes back to however high it's maximum has become*.

This means in the beginning the hunters respawn very quickly, but as the match plays out and more fights ensue and other events occur, then the timer will become longer giving the monster the advantage.